# Infinite Safari history on iPad?

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari, browser-history

I really don't like to bookmark things (on iPad or other platforms) but just type a few relevent letters that bring the right site from browser history as a suggestion. However, on iPad I noticed that when I haven't visited a site for a while, Safari no longer suggests sites it previously did.

So, it seems that the browsing history is limited, by days or by size, am I right? I tried to stop Safari automatically deleting page history or at least increase the history size but there's nothing relevant in Settings for Safari.

Is adding a bookmark for every site I want to be suggested for sure the only option? Are there any restrictions for amount of bookmarks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPad seems to limit its history to a week, which is presumably an acknowledgement of the limited RAM and storage in comparison to a traditional computer.

Adding bookmarks for desired/frequent sites is the only way to make sure they come up easily.  There is no practical limit to the number of bookmarks, and you could easily shove all of those bookmarks in a folder you never visit directly.

Comment: Indeed on my orginal iPad the history has way too short life duration — a week or so. Now, on modern iPads and modern iOS, things have improved, fortunately. See my coming answer.

Comment: At one time, Apple *claimed* that bookmark capacity was limited to 25,000 items. Later the published limit was raised to 50,000 items; I’m unsure if there is an _actual_ limit anymore, though. Unlike the Microsoft Edge browser *(which syncs individual bookmark / history enteries)*, at one time it seemed like iCloud synced the whole database file when it changed. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯