# How much Safari history is kept on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, browser-history

How many Safari history entries are kept on iPads until automatically deleted?
(Not sure if this depends on iPad model or version of iOS…)

Answer (score 1):

- On iOS 5 (and maybe 6), the limit is a strict **1 week**.
- On iOS 7 and later, the limit is around 1 week depending on iCloud sync status.

It is currently not possible to increase this limit for Safari:

- [Infinite Safari history on iPad?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6310/infinite-safari-history-on-ipad)

Comment: What about iOS 8 and 9? Now, on iOS 8, the limit is *around* 1 month, but not exactly. I want to know the exact limit. Besides, Apple told me about a limit of 4000 entries, if I remember correctly.

Comment: What about iOS 11?

Comment: Do you have the info about iOS 16? It seems to be or abt 3 months ago or having too much entries (how much maximum?)